# Is there a built in way to parse an incomplete xml-text in Javascript in the latest Firefox?

Tags: html, xml, firefox, doctype, dtd

I have read the answers so far, that DOMParser can't handle incomplete (and because of that not well formed) XML-Data.

As all major browsers can handle faulty html-source I just wonder if it's possible to use a workaround to get the browser interpreting the not well formed XML-Data.
For example by putting a manually written DOCTYPE-tag with an ATTLIST at the start of the Data, and then telling the browser to interpret it in a hidden frame, and then using the resulting dom-tree?

**Is there a built in way to parse an incomplete xml-text in Javascript in the latest Firefox?**
or
 
**How would the DOCTYPE and ADDLIST have to look like, if in the Data there are unknown tags like `<mytag>` with attributes like `nr="..."` and `date="..."?` and `<anothertag>`with attributes like `nr="..."` and `upto="..."?`**

Answer (score 1):

Just use a DOMParser.

```js
function parseFragment(fragment) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        doc = parser.parseFromString(fragment, "text/html");
    return doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
}
```

and

```js
var root = parseFragment('<foo><bar some="thing"><baz></bar>');

console.log(root.getElementsByTagName("bar")[0].getAttribute("some"));
// -> "thing"
```

Comment: It seemed to work perfectly, thank you! But now I ran into some other problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053868/domparser-parsefromstringtext-text-html-only-interprets-the-first-21-500-by
which seems to me to be a bug in the browser. :/

Comment: You can't expect any magic. If your input is broken beyond a certain point, the "blunt force" approach  above will no longer work.

Comment: No, it must be a bug or the function is not well documented. If I remember correctly I tried it even with the full original XML-data, and the restriction appeared anyway. -  Actually the documentation over at Mozilla looks bad in it's structure, not like the newer documentation styles I have seen lately. - I will take a look in the ECMA definition, though as far as I have read it's maybe not defined in there. - So far I have gone back to parseFromString with "application/xml" type and fixing the xml-parts with manually correcting and adding start and end tags. This works.

Comment: About the data: It's maximum three levels of tags. Very simple style. And the parts were just cut out of the original well formed XML-data. Especially that the restriction appeared when I used parseFromString with "text/HTML" on a long part of the original XML-data starting with it's very beginning seems to make it obvious to me, there must be some serious design fault in the parser. - The original XML-data is procedural generated. It's .OSM (openstreetmap) data.

Comment: Another thing is that the addons can interfer with uncommon javascript and without giving any error message even. (First hand experience. :/ ) I might check that, once I find time.

Comment: I don't think we can argue about the "documentation style" of the MDN,  I hope you can see how that is *completely* besides the point. Also the function certainly doesn't have "a bug" just because it doesn't work the way you imagine. If I were you I would start thinking about ways of not sending horribly broken dats to the browser in the first place. That's about all I can say to this.