# DOMParser.parseFromString(text,"text/html") only interprets the first ~21,500 Bytes. Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-parsing, promise, domparser

I have Win 7, 64 Bit, Firefox 32.0.1, Noscript running.

The following code only returns 199 nodes with aXML.getElementsByTagName("node"), whereas there are 300 in the parsed text, which is not well formed xml.

```
var atext = '';
for (var i=0;i<300;i++) {
    atext += '  <node id="'+i+'" lat="42.5168939" lon="1.553855" version="2" changeset="21730124"/>'+"\n\r";
}
parser = new DOMParser();
aXML= parser.parseFromString(atext , "text/html");
console.log(" nodes: " + aXML.getElementsByTagName("node").length
        +"\n\r atext.length:" + atext.length);
console.log(aXML.getElementsByTagName('node'));
```

The console shows:

```
" nodes: 199

 atext.length:25390"
HTMLCollection [ <node#0>, <node#1>, <node#2>, <node#3>, <node#4>, <node#5>, <node#6>, <node#7>, <node#8>, <node#9>, 189 weitere… ]
```

Could this be a bug?

The web-console doesn't show any error from parseFromString.

(I get a log of other errors lately, that I can't put in any relation to the open tabs.

```
A promise chain failed to handle a rejection.
Date: Sat Mar 14 2015 22:01:10 GMT+0100
Full Message: null
```

Could that be related?)

Comment: Can you reduce this to a smaller file that reproduces the problem (small enough that you could include it in the question) ?

Comment: No one is going to read 25k of xml. Keep removing bits of the file until you have a very small file that exhibits the problem

Comment: @FrederickCheung: There we go, I made an example code with javascript.

Comment: What browser was used to test this?

Comment: @Anonymous: I have Win 7, 64 Bit, Firefox 32.0.1, Noscript running. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to parse XML as HTML. The two are quite different in terms of valid syntax. Instead of using:

```
aXML= parser.parseFromString(atext , "text/html");
```

You need to instead use:

```
aXML= parser.parseFromString(atext , "text/xml");
```

Also, make sure the XML is valid or it will not parse. In your example, it is not, but I assume that is just a test case.

Comment: No, it's not well formed XML in the real use case.

Comment: In order for it to parse, it needs to either be valid XML or HTML. The example is neither.

Comment: TIP: When parsing web components with `text/xml` the life cycle events such as `connectedCallback` will be ignored. This will affect the inner workigns of the components. Use `text/html` in this case